# Do not change input focus after clicking on PyQt application

Tags: windows, pyqt

I want to create virtual keyboard to write text using only mouse with clicks in windows 10-11.

I can't use standart virtual keyboard as I plan to use another keyboard layout.

And here is a standart way to use this keyboard: user click where he want to enter text, clicks on application to enter character, character is entered and user can continue entering character.

Rihgt now I have problem: focus is changhing on my application. Right after clicking on application focus is on it, but not in the place where I want to enter text.

Here is simple example of pyqt application:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
lb = QPushButton("Button A", parent=window)
window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

So what I need to do for start:
user click on text editor somewhere, click in button A in this application, and after that character A entering in text editor. After that user clickclick on this button again, new character A in entering and so on.

Simple solution is to press Alt+tab after user click on button, but it is not beautifull case.